# I'm trying to get edit text value in adapter class and store in Array list but text are store one character by character

Tags: android, android-adapter

Here is my code used for getting text

```
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            selectedItems.add(holder.getAdapterPosition(),s.toString());

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do with FocusChangeListener. It has a boolean parameter hasFocus. When this is false, you've lost focus to another control.

Example code:

```
EditText txtEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittxt);
txtEdit.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {          
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (!hasFocus) {
           // code to execute when EditText loses focus
          selectedItems.add(holder.getAdapterPosition(),txtEdit.getText().toString());
        }
    }
});
```

Also note, when you click on edittxt again, after that you lose focus on edittext then again above FocusChangeListener will execute.